# How to get compiler error messages with complete imports in visual studio code for typescript?

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, visual-studio-code

I'm editing a piece of typescript code in visual studio code. For this I receive a compiler error message that reads like:

```
Type 'import(\"c:/path/to/project/node_modules/@com.m...' is not assignable to type 
'import(\"c:/path/to/project/node_modules/@com.m...'. Two different types with this name 
exist, but they are unrelated.
```

What do I need to configure in order to read the full paths for the imports in the compiler error message?

Comment: Try `"noErrorTruncation": true` in your `tsconifg.json`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir your suggestion works. Thanks. You may add this as an answer.

Comment: Relevant github issue and comment on the matter: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26238#issuecomment-672086446

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add the option to not truncate in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
"noErrorTruncation": true
```

The compiler options [page](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) does not offer a lot of information about what gets truncated but if you disable truncation you should get all the information the compiler has about the error at the cost of longer errors.